# How to launch a file browser in a Qt application?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to have a button that, when clicked, launches a file browser (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in Word) and returns the path of the file that user opens.

I know how to make the button, but what should I do in the slot that responds to `mouseClicked` signal?

Answer (score 22):

Use [`QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName).

Answer (score 19):

What you need to do is write this code in your mouse_click function !

```
QStringList fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Open File"),"/path/to/file/",tr("Mp3 Files (*.mp3)"));
ui->listWidget->addItems(fileNames);
```

`*.mp3` will display only mp3 files remove the `tr("Mp3 Files (*.mp3)")` if you dont want to filter any files

Comment: What is ui here?  What is its type?

Comment: UI is your main ui component where your adding this

Comment: You can specify the default path with QDir::currentPath()